# Determine whether a set is closed?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and Topology $T=\{\{1,2,3\}, \{1,2\}, \{3\},\emptyset\}$.

If $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{1,2\}$. Are they closed?
I am stuck on this question. How can we find the complement of the given $X$? Shouldn't there be more information?

Comment: Have you written down the topology correctly? Did you perhaps mean $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and $\tau=\{\{X,\{1,2\},\{3\},\emptyset\}$?

Comment: Yes you are right! Thank you

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld, it is polite to wait a while before editing somebody else's question.

Comment: @EricStucky Hm, if I am going to do the edit anyway, why is one timing more impolite than another? Btw, if the OP feels offended by the edit he is perfectly justified to roll it back.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld: If the OP had *already* made your intended edit, in full, you  probably would not have done it anyway. An edit means "The OP is unable or unwilling to make the same quality of contribution to their own question as I am." Fast edits imply "unable", because you haven't left enough time to see if the OP is willing. So if the edit is also insubstantial, it feels like you are stating publicly that the OP is incompetent. I didn't see that you also formatted the question, so I retract my objection to this edit; to me a conversion from plaintext to LaTeX is substantial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the definition of a closed set $U\subset X$ is a subset such that $X\setminus U$ is an open set (that is $X\setminus U\in\tau$).

Now, for $A=\{1\}$ we have $X\setminus A=\{2,3\}$ and for $B=\{1,2\}$ we have $X\setminus B=\{3\}$. Can you see these sets in the topology $\tau=\{X,\{1,2\},\{3\},\emptyset\}$?

Comment: Ah! I see Daniel. I was thinking about complements as something outside of X given a specific universe. Ideas are much clear now. Thank you!

Comment: @MarkRutherford You're welcome! At the start of learning topology it can seem pretty abstract, but after the technicalities are out of the way it should seem **much** more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

The complement of the subset $A$ is every element in $X$ which is not in $A$. So if you know the elements of $X$ and the elements $A$, you have enough information to find the complement. What points in $X$ are not in $A$? Clearly the answer is $2$ and $3$. So the complement of $A$ is $\{2, 3\}$. Is this set open? Well it's not a subset of the topology on $X$ so by definition the answer is no. Just use this same process to determine if $B$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Your information here is a bit sketchy.  I believe that $X$ here is the listing of open sets in the topology you are considering.  (In pointset topology, one describes the topology by explicitly listing the open sets.  The only thing that troubles me is that the empty set should have been included as a member of the set $X$, and I don't see it there.)

Anyway, if I interpret things correctly, this is a topology with pointset $S=\{1,2,3\}$ whose open sets are the members of $X$ (although, as I said above, $\emptyset$ is somehow missing).  A *closed* set is a set that is the complement of n open set, where complementation is always performed relative to the pointset ($S=\{1,2,3\}$ in this case).  Thus the complement of $\{1\}$ would be $\{2,3\}$.

As $\{2,3\}$ is not a member of $X$, it is not open.  Thus $A=\{1\}$ is not closed.  On the other hand, $B=\{1,2\}$ is closed.  (Can you see why?)

Comment: Should we check {2,3} as a member of $X$ or $T$

Comment: The notation used in this question has changed over time.  As it now stands, you would check that $\{2,3\}$ is a member of $T$.  In the notation originally posted, you would check that $\{2,3\}$ is a member of $X$.